# Are there any advantages in using block initialization?

Tags: ruby, initialization

Is there any reason to do use block initialization, like this:

```
x = Observer.new do
  add_event(foo)
  some_other_instance_method_on_observer
  self.some_attribute = something
end
```

instead of initializing attributes using the dot operator on an instance variable like this:

```
x = Observer.new
x.add_event(foo)
x.some_other_instance_method_on_observer
x.some_attribute = something
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason here is to have more concise code(you don't have to add the instance name before the method call). By using blocks in general you can write very neat, concise and readable code. Some times you can save your code consumers lots of typing and even code logic.
Here is a traditional case!

```
file = File.open("some_file.txt","w")
file << "more code"
file.close
```

Compare it to this nice block alternative:

```
File.open("some_file.txt","w") { |file| file << "adding new stuff" }
```

It saved the user from the hassle of having to open and close(personally i keep forgetting this one) the file himself. Instead it made him focus on what he wants.

Try to invest blocks in such situations + when you want to write nice DSLs.

Answer (score 4):

One advantage is that it makes it obvious that those additional actions are initialization actions.

Answer (score 1):

Building on khell's answer, variables created within a block go out of scope outside of the block, which is a good thing if you don't have any more use of it.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is in a method, which returns the object.  Compare

```
def create_observer
    Observer.new {|x| x.foo, x.bar = calculate_foo, calculate_bar }
end

def create_observer
    x = Observer.new
    x.foo = calculate_foo
    x.bar = calculate_bar
    x
end
```

So using a block can potentially allow you to write your logic in one line.
Even if you use parallel assignment in the second example, you still need 3 lines.

Also, check out `tap` [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-tap).  It has similar benefits.